# Like - unlike system in MongoDb to find if user liked or not?

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I'm trying to make a middleware for cheaking if user already liked the post for a React-toggle on click I've achieved a pretty good way in it in front end which i'm able to find weather user liked the post or not then toggle the button, the problem is i'm trying to match it in backend side to cheak if the likes array in schema already has the userId or not

the middleware be like

```html
exports.liked = async (req, res, next) => {
  const Liked = await Post.find( { likes : { $elemMatch: req.body.userId } } )
  if (Liked){
    return res.status(400).json({
      error: "AlreadyLiked",
    })} else {next()}
    
};
```

my mongoose schema is

```html
let postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    minlength: 4,
    maxength: 150,
  },
  body: {
    type: String,
    required: "Body is required",
    minLength: 1,
    maxLength: 2500,
  },
  photo: {
    data: Buffer,
    contentType: String,
  },
  
  postedBy: {
    type: ObjectId,
    ref: "User",
  },
  created: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },likes: [{ type: ObjectId, ref: "User" }]
});
```

I aprreciate helps, thanks in first :)